# Estilo das widgets de um programa usando PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pip, pyqt-5

Estive criando uma espécie de software de edição de texto utilizando python3.5 e PyQt5, e na etapa de criação dos pacotes acabei notando que a versão de desenvolvimento, que usava um pacote de PyQt5 gerenciado pelo sistema operacional, tinha um visual diferente da obtida pela criação do pacote, que usava um pacote PyQt5 gerenciado pelo pip. Após uma pesquisa, descobrir que poderia usar o método [QStyleFactory.keys](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstylefactory.html#keys) para listar todos os estilos de widgets disponíveis, e o resultado deste método no pacote PyQt5 do pip foi apenas ['Windows', 'Fusion'], sendo nenhum destes nativo do meu SO.

- Há algum outro pacote complementar ou algum outro procedimento que permita o pacote PyQt5 do pip utilizar outros estilos de widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, encontrei [esse repositório](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtstyleplugins.git/tree/) que possui outros estilos de widget que podem ser carregados, e também [as folhas de estilo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) que podem modificar os estilos de widget.